# RAD Studio c++ template generic event blocker

Tags: c++, templates, c++builder, c++03

I've been having problems with RAD Studio XE components triggering a cascade of events - like when component A in-code modification altered content of component B which triggered change in component C etc.
Long story short - made some blocking mechanism via RAII pattern. Multiple of them, depending on the type of event I needed to be blocked, like OnSelect or OnChange:

```
template<typename T, typename N>
class TOnChangeEventBlocker
{
public:
    TOnChangeEventBlocker(T* object)
        :m_pObject(object)
        ,m_pNotifyEvent(object->OnChange)
    {
        if (m_pObject)
        {
            m_pObject->OnChange = NULL;
        }
    }

    ~TOnChangeEventBlocker()
    {
        if (m_pObject)
        {
            m_pObject->OnChange = m_pNotifyEvent;
        }
    }
private:
    T* const    m_pObject;
    N           m_pNotifyEvent;
};
```

Is there a way to make it more generic? Make it work with the *__property* exposed private event handlers?

Instead of writing a plethora of event blockers have: one, simple, generic TEventBlocker.

```
m_pObject->/*something here*/ = m_pNotifyEvent;
```

It's a legacy code and RAD Studio XE project - not much of c++11 there.

---

I followed @Jarod42 trail of member pointer and the breadcrumbs led me to the final solution:

```
template <typename T>
    class TEventBlocker
    {
    public:
        TEventBlocker(T* f)
            : eventFunctionClassMember(f)
            , eventFunction(NULL)
        {
            if (eventFunctionClassMember && *eventFunctionClassMember)
            {
                eventFunction               = *eventFunctionClassMember;
                *eventFunctionClassMember   = NULL;
            }
        }
        ~TEventBlocker()
        {
            if (eventFunctionClassMember)
            {
                *eventFunctionClassMember   = eventFunction;
            }
        }
    private:
        T*  eventFunctionClassMember;
        T   eventFunction;
    };
```

Calling it (have to be explicit about the template argument):

```
TEventBlocker<Classes::TNotifyEvent> blockSelect(&(SelectComponent->OnSelect));
```

Comment: it seems you only need a pointer "restorer".

Comment: If you've defined event handlers for your components and disable them like this, doesn't the result become wrong? What's the problem with the cascading effect? Is it circular?

Comment: @TedLyngmo To make it clear. Component is not getting disabled, just the event handler for the scope of the logic that requires that particular event to remain in such a state. I wouldn't like anyone to dwell on the nature of "why" - it works. Trust me =) I'm only looking for a generic solution within constraints imposed by dev environment.

Comment: Got it - I was just asking because I've never found myself in the same predicament so I was hoping that you perhaps had made some mistake.

Comment: You might be interested by [Pointers_to_members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members).

Comment: @Jarod42 C++ Builder has a language extension making pointers to instance->members possible. My first C++ experience was with C++ Builder and I was a bit confused that this wasn't standard at first when I stepped out of the C++ Builder zone..

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only need to take the member:

```
template <typename T>
class EventBlocker
{
public:
    EventBlocker(T& event)
        :m_event(event), m_old(event)
    {
        m_event = NULL; // nullptr; in C++11
    }

    ~EventBlocker()
    {
        m_event = m_old;
    }

private:
    EventBlocker(const EventBlocker&); // = delete; in C++11
    EventBlocker& operator=(const EventBlocker&); // = delete; in c++11

private:
    T& m_event;
    T m_old;
};

// C++17 CTAD would be enough, but before:
template <typename T>
EventBlocker<T> make_EventBlocker(T& event) { return {event}; }
```

And then:

```
auto eventBlocker = make_EventBlocker(myObject->OnChange);
// ...
```

Comment: "It's a legacy code and RAD Studio XE project - not much of c++11 there." Compiler adheres to c++03 standard, there is no c++11 support.

Comment: @JimMoore: use the old way: make method private without implementation, instead of `= delete`.